# Why docker run can't find file which was copied during build

Tags: docker

Dockerfile

```
FROM centos

RUN mkdir /test

#its ensured that sample.sh exists where the dockerFile exists & being run
 
COPY ./sample.sh /test

CMD ["sh", "/test/sample.sh"]
```

Docker run cmd:

`docker run -d -p 8081:8080 --name Test -v /home/Docker/Container_File_System:/test test:v1`

**Log output :**

```
sh: /test/sample.sh: No such file or directory
```

There are 2 problems here.

- The output says sh: /test/sample.sh: No such file or directory
- as I have mapped a host folder to container folder, I was expecting the test folder & the sample.sh to be available at /home/Docker/Container_File_System post run, which did not happen

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the Container_File_System folder contains the sample.sh?

Answer (score 1):

When you map a folder from the host to the container, the host files become available in the container. This means that if your host has file a.txt and the container has b.txt, when you run the container the file a.txt becomes available in the container and the file b.txt is no longer visible or accessible.

Additionally file b.txt is not available in the host at anytime.

In your case, since your host does not have sample.sh, the moment you mount the directory, sample.sh is no longer available in the container (which causes the error).
What you want to do is copy the sample.sh file to the correct directory in the host and then start the container.

Comment: Thanks. how would I be able to create the folders(which are copied while building the image) in host itself when I run the container?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in volume mapping. If I create a volume and map it subsequently it works fine, but directly mapping host folder to container folder does not work.

Below worked fine

```
docker volume create my-vol

docker run -d -p 8081:8080 --name Test -v my-vol:/test test:v1
```